# access user data header of the sms

Tags: android, header, sms

Is it possible to extract the user data header from an sms message? if yes, any ideas on how to proceed with it? 
also, is it possible to make changes to the data header before sending an sms?

Answer (score 0):

the source code for receive a sms goes:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onReceive");
        if (extras == null)
            return;

        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");

        for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
            SmsMessage message = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            String fromAddress = message.getOriginatingAddress();
            String messageBody = message.getMessageBody().toString();

            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "From: " + fromAddress + " message: " + messageBody);

            addNotification(context, fromAddress, messageBody);
        }
    }
```

so,it was byte[] type, so if you have a good knowledge of UDH  which is described in [User Data Header](http://smstools3.kekekasvi.com/index.php?p=udh), I think it is possible.

Comment: thanks. but i am new to this. do u have any idea how to extract the udh value from it?

Comment: if you are going to simply get the udh from a SmsMessage you can refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage.html#getUserData()

Comment: this just gives the user data. and not the user data header    `public byte[] getUserData ()

Added in API level 4
returns the user data section minus the user data header if one was present.`